# Как исправить ошибки?

Tags: java

Добрый день! Написал программку на Java для скачивания изображения по URL, но как надо она не работает.

Вот код метода

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://djvu2pdf.com/images/djvu2pdf/logo.png");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);

   ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("D:\\testing"));

}
```

Собственно ошибки

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\testing (Отказано в доступе)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(FileImageOutputStream.java:69)
at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(FileImageOutputStreamSpi.java:55)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:419)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1530)
at Parser.main(Parser.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1538)
at Parser.main(Parser.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас просто нет прав на то, чтобы писать в корень диска D.

Comment: Хорошо, а как выдать права? Т.е. мне придется выдать их на саму idea? (Уже пытался выдать, но видимо не так как надо)

Comment: Выдача прав - это уже вопрос из области системного администрирования и к java отношения не имеет. По видимому вам надо зайти на вкладку "Безопасность" свойств диска и выдать разрешение самому себе писать в корень диска.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.